# Where is markup stored for $form['name'])

Tags: drupal, markup

I'm not much into Drupal, but need to figure out this little thing. In one of tpl.php page a have following:

```php
<?php print drupal_render($form['name']); ?>
```

Which renders following HTML:

```html
<div id="username-check-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item" id="edit-name-wrapper">
        <label for="edit-name">Username:
            <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="60" name="name" id="edit-name" size="60"
            value="" class="form-text required" />
        <div class="description">
            Must be at least 8 characters and contain no spaces
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to change this HTML, how can I figure out where the actual markup is stored

Comment: There's must be more `$form` elements in this `.tpl.php` file. Can you give whole file code?

Comment: If you want to change the markup of a form you should read more about **theming forms** . Check [this](http://drupal.org/project/examples) out. It is a great collection of modules you can look at the code and learn how things are done in Drupal

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can alter this form using the hook: [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).
With this hook, you can modify the form adding or removing elements from it. Basicly, you will need to create a module just to build it in your way.

But if you want to style it differently, just edit the css from your theme. Or include another specific one.